# jqGrid giving "No such method" when calling setFrozenColumns in cell editing mode

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am trying to freeze columns using `setFrozenColumns` but am getting error "jqGrid - No such method: setFrozenColumns".

I'm using jqGrid version 4.4.1.

Can anybody please show me the exact cause of this issue?

(I have also set jqGrid cellEditing true and I am aware of limitations of frozenColumns. But, still want to freeze some columns).

Your cooperation will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhilash

Comment: add the code you use to initialize jqgrid, please.